# How is my list assignment is out of range?

Tags: python

I'm new to python and trying to understand 2D arrays. I'm trying to write a code in which someone inputs and stores the employee ID, department, and salary for 10 employees. Which is then stored using a 2D array The following will be outputted:

- All the information with the appropriate column title
- How many employees are working in each department. Output it with the department name
- Input the department as accounts, admin and sales

This is my code:

```
EmpID = ""
Departement = ""
Salary = ""
EmpDetails = [[0 for c in range(3)] for r in range(4)]
for r in range(4):
    EmpDetails[r][1]=(input("Enter the Employee ID: "))
    EmpDetails[r][2]=(input("Enter the Department: "))
    EmpDetails[r][3]=int(input("Enter the Salary: "))
print("Employee ID     Department     Salary")
for r in range(4):
    for c in range(3):
        print(EmpDetails[r][c], end = " ")
        print() #??
        Account=0
        Adcount=0
        Scount=0
        for r in range(4):
            if EmpDetails[r][2] == "Accounts":
                Accounts=Account+1
            elif EmpDetails[r][2] == "Admin":
                Adcount=Adcount+1
            else:
                Scount=Scount+1
            print("Account: ", Account, "Employees")
            print("Admin: ", Adcount, "Employees")
            print("Sales: ", Scount, "Employees")
```

When I'm running the module, and error comes out at:

```
Enter the Employee ID: 1
Enter the Department: Accounts
Enter the Salary: 1000
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/Documents/2darray.py", line 8, in <module>
    EmpDetails[r][3]=int(input("Enter the Salary: "))
IndexError: list assignment index out of range
```

I'm so confused as to how my list assignment is out of range? I can't get past this so can't continue on. Thank you in advance!

Comment: `EmpDetails[r][3]` references the **4th** element of `EmpDetails[r]`.  Since there are only three such elements, trying to access the 4th element produces the error you're seeing.  You want to use `[0], [1], [2]` rather than `[1], [2], [3]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python is zero-indexed. When inputting EmpDetails, use indexes 0, 1, 2 instead.